# How to apply localizationsDelegates for specific screens and not all of them in flutter project?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. I need to make my application directionality from right to left but only for some specific screens. But for the others I want them to stay as default. What I found is :

```
localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
```

In the `Material App` widget. But this applies it for all the screens which is not what I want. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Directionality to specify the text direction. For more info here is [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: i want to specify the whole screen direction not only the text